# Reporting Services - Report Paramaters Losing State

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I am embedding a report into my ASP.NET app using the report viewer control.

When I change a paramater value and click View Report, I'm losing my paramater selection.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was setting the report location in the code behind but not che3cking if there had been a postback so the report was being reset each time.

Answer (score 1):

Check if ViewState is enabled (for the page and for the control)